# Prove $\binom{n}{0}$ + $\binom{n}{2}$ + $\binom{n}{4} + ...+\binom{n}{n-1}=\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{5}+...+\binom{n}{n}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

I want to prove that $\binom{n}{0}$ + $\binom{n}{2}$ + $\binom{n}{4} + ...+\binom{n}{n-1}=\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{5}+...+\binom{n}{n}$ for all odd numbers $n \ge 1$

I see that $\binom{n}{0}$ and $\binom{n}{n}$ are both equal to $1$ and therefor remove each other.

But what can I do after that? I'm very lost, please help me move in the right direction at least.

Comment: Hint:$$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}  $$

Comment: Expand $(1-1)^n$ using the binomial theorem .

Comment: If you are only proving this for odd numbers, then you are already nearly there with what you noticed... $\binom{n}{0}$ and $\binom{n}{n}$ are equal and can cancel.  $\binom{n}{2}$ and $\binom{n}{n-2}$ are equal and can cancel, and so on and so forth.  What is perhaps more interesting is that this is true for *even* $n$ as well (*though it should have been more carefully phrased since the appearance of the last term for each is different*)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an intuitive combinatorial proof.  The left-hand side is the number of even-sized subsets of an $n$-set, which we'll call $X$.  The right-hand side is the number of odd-sized subsets of $X$.  But $Y \mapsto X \setminus Y$ is a $1$-$1$ mapping of even-sized subsets onto odd-sized subsets, so the two numbers must be equal.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove by induction on $n$ that
$$\sum_{k} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} =0$$
for all $n\ge 1$. For $n=1$ it's easy to check. Assume that it's true for some $n\ge 1$. Denote by $a_k = \binom{n}{k}$, $a_k'= \binom{n+1}{k}$. So we have
$$\sum_{k}(-1)^k a_k = 0$$
and want to show that
$$\sum_{k} (-1)^k a_k'=0$$
We have (Pascal triangle)
$$a_{k}' = a_k+ a_{k-1}$$
Now break the sum $\sum_k (-1)^k a_k'$ into two sums.

$\bf{Added:}$
In a similar way one proves by induction on $n$ that
$$\sum_k \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$$
or even
$$\sum_k x^k \binom{n}{k} = (1+x)^n$$

Comment: Why induction? simply use the binomial theorem, as suggested by Pavel R. in the comments. (That theorem may also have been proved by induction but it certainly belongs to the OP's toolbox.)

Comment: @Anne Bauval: I was just trying to recall how things work. You made a valid point, thank you!